# C language - structure

Tags: c, file-io, structure

When execute second `fscanf`, console stop working.  What did I do wrong?

The input file contains:

```
3
minsu 50 80 40
sarah 30 60 40
jason 70 80 90
```

The code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct studentT {
    char *name;
    int literature;
    int math;
    int science;
}studentT;

int main()
{
    studentT student[3];
    int count;
    char *inputFileName = malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
    char *outputFileName = malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
    float avg;
    int i = 0;

    scanf("%s %s", inputFileName, outputFileName);

    FILE *fp = fopen(inputFileName, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("file is not exist");
        return 1;
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &count);

    for (i = 0; i < (int)count; i++)
    {
        //printf("!");
        fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d %d", student[i].name, &student[i].literature, &student[i].math, &student[i].science);
        //printf("2");
        printf("%s %d %d %d\n", student[i].name, student[i].literature, student[i].math, student[i].science);
        //printf("333\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
    free(inputFileName);
    free(outputFileName);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s %s", inputFileName, outputFileName);`  1) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  (in general, returned the number of successful input format conversions so would be 2 for this example)  2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]', always include a MAX CHARACTERs modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: OT:regarding: `printf("file is not exist");`  This is not necessarily true.  Suggest: `perror( "fopen failed" ) as this outputs to `stderr` both the error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, follow my prior comment about `scanf()`

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of statement: `char *inputFileName = malloc(sizeof(char)*30);`  1) the expression `sizeof(char)` is always 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect suggest removing that expressionchar *inputFileName = malloc(sizeof(char)*30);  2) suggest replacing these kind of statements with: `char inputFileName[30] = {'\0'};`  This would also allow removing the calls to `free()`

Comment: OT: the posted code inputs two file names, but only access one of those files

Comment: OT: regarding: `for (i = 0; i < (int)count; i++)`  the variable `count` is already an `int`. so no need to cast it to `int`

Comment: OT: regarding the typedef of the struct, it is a poor programming practice (although often seen) to use the same name for the typedef as the tag name for the struct

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s %s", inputFileName, outputFileName);`  this will leave the user looking at a blinking cursor and no idea that they need to input a input file name and a output file name.  Suggest prompting the user

Comment: regarding: `char *name;`  and `fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d %d", student[i].name, &student[i].literature, &student[i].math, &student[i].science);`  The pointer `name` is never initialized to point to some memory that the application owns. Writing data to whereever that pointer points is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` field in your `studentT` struct is a `char *`.  You pass that pointer to `scanf` without initializing it to anything.  So `scanf` reads an uninitialized pointer and tried to dereference it.  This invokes undefined behavior.

The simplest way to fix this is to change `name` to be an array large enough to hold any string you expect.  Then you can write to the array:

```
typedef struct studentT {
    char name[20];
    int literature;
    int math;    
    int science;
}studentT;
```

Alternately, you can use `malloc` to allocate space dynamically:

```
student[i].name = malloc(20);
fscanf(fp, "%19s %d %d %d", student[i].name, &student[i].literature, 
                            &student[i].math, &student[i].science);
```

Comment: Oh thanks!! But i must use char name*. So i can't fix it. Can you recommend another way???

Comment: @양우열 You'll need to allocate space for a string with `malloc`.

Comment: @양우열 Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: I'm first StackOverflow. So how can i accept this answer?? Just click your answer???